# InvalidProjectFileException with using Microsoft.NET.Sdk in Microsoft.Build.Evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I want to parse a C#-project to read out all project- and other references. For months, I used the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` namespace from the package `Microsoft.Build`.

```cs
var file = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory, "*.csproj").First();
var project = new Project(test);
```

For the old csproj-files it is working fine without any problem. The old files are starting with

`<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

Since migrating to the new SDK-Project style, I have some problems with reading the csproj files. They start with

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`

When loading the project I get the following exception: `InvalidProjectFileException: 'The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.` I figured out, if I change the Version of the package `Microsoft.Build` to the version of my Visual Studio/MSBuild (e.g. 16.8) it works fine. I have a lot of colleagues with a high variety of MSBuild Versions >15 and we cannot have all the same MSBuild version.

A possible solution which I have found is to add the `Microsoft.Build.Runtime` package but if I add it to my project I get a lot of compiler errors and no type is found which works before.

The project which should load the csproj files is a `ToolsVersion="4.0"`-project style with .NET Framework 4.7.2 (cannot change this to SDK project style because of massive T4 template usage).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  Seems similar to this question as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121531/why-do-we-get-this-invalidprojectfileexception-exception-when-using-the-microsof

Comment: No, unfortunately not